# How to use compiled rtmp-dump for building iOS app

Tags: ios, dump, rtmp

How can I use the compiled version of rtmpdump  https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/ to make an iOS app ?
The compiled library i.e  librtmp.a is available https://github.com/BigBadOwl/iPhone-Rtmpdump  but the sample xcode project is quite old and not very useful. Can someone provide good sample project or tutorial ?

Comment: Have you used rtmp url to play video streaming in ios? please provide help.